# Detect the presence or absence of a string in a pattern with Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner in python coding. I need a hand to find an elegant way to do this:

I've got the following dataframe :

```
  pattern  nb
1   a,b,c  150
2       b  100
3     c,b  30
4       c  10
```

According to the presence of string, I want a dataframe like that :

```
  pattern   nb    a    b     c
1   a,b,c   150   150  150   150
2       b   100   0    100   0
3     c,b   30    0    30    30
4       c   10    0    0     10
```

Many thanks in advance.

Greetings from France

Arnaud

Comment: Are your patterns always comma-separated like that? And do they reliably not contain a comma?

Comment: Hello, not necessarily a comma but it's always the same.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way but this will do what you are after:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pattern = ['a,b,c', 'b', 'c,b', 'c']
nb = [150, 100, 30, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.column_stack([pattern, nb]), columns=['pattern', 'nb'])
df
>>>   pattern   nb
    0   a,b,c  150
    1       b  100
    2     c,b   30
    3       c   10
```

And then you can check the values, add the correct value to a list and then add to the DataFrame at the end:

```
# we want to check whether a, b, or c is in the original pattern
# so we loop over a, b, and c one at a time
for value in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    # when we do our check we want to store the values
    # so we initialise an empty list that we will use to add the values toused 
    new = [] 

    # now we loop over each pattern in the original DataFrame
    # enumerate is gives us back an index 'i' and a value 'p' ('p' for pattern in this case)
    # just like normal for loop
    # we need the index 'i' later to access the DataFrame values  
    for i, p in enumerate(df['pattern']): 

        # we now do a test to see if value (ie. a, b, or c) is in 'p'
        if value in p:
            # if it is we get the value of the pattern from the original DataFrame -> df['nb'].iloc[I]
            # df['nb'] selects the column in the DataFrame
            # and .iloc[i] gets the correct row
            # and we add it to the list
            new.append(df['nb'].iloc[i])
        else:
            # if a, b, or c is not in the pattern we add 0 to the list
            new.append(0)

    # after one iteration of the loop (a, b, c) and all tests
    # we then add a new column to the DataFrame
    # value in this case is 'a', 'b', or 'c'
    # so the column names are 'a', 'b' or 'c'
    df[value] = new

df
>>>   pattern   nb    a    b    c
    0   a,b,c  150  150  150  150
    1       b  100    0  100    0
    2     c,b   30    0   30   30
    3       c   10    0    0   10
```

Comment: Paddy, Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I'm gonna meditate on that just to figure out the structure of your code. As I said : I'm a newbie in Python.

Comment: Hi Arnaud, I've added some more comments to the code which hopefully explain it a bit more thoroughly. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way which uses the fact that your patterns are separated by a delimiter:

```
def splitter(row):
    """Split pattern and return a Series object"""
    return pd.Series(row['nb'], index=row['pattern'].split(','))

# Apply this function to each row of the dataframe and fill in the blanks
extra_cols = df.apply(splitter, axis=1).fillna(0)

# join the new columns back to the main dataframe
df.join(extra_cols)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your very efficient answer.